# Wordpress Query inside Shortcode Doesn't Display on Page

Tags: php, wordpress

After digging around StackOverflow and putting together pieces of code, I managed to formulate this below code.  However, I can't seem to figure out why it won't display on the page.

At the present time I just have the word "test" just to see if the loop would fire.

What is the issue?

```
<?php add_shortcode( 'jobs-search-results', 'jobs_search_results' );
function jobs_search_results() {
       ob_start();
​
       $jobs_search_results_args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'job' ),
        'meta_query'             => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'client_state',
                'value'     => 'Alabama',
            ),
        ),
       );
​
       $jobs_search_results_query = new WP_Query( $jobs_search_results_args );
​
       if ( $jobs_search_results_query->have_posts() ) : while($jobs_search_results_query->have_posts()) : $jobs_search_results_query->the_post();
       ?>
              test
​
       <?php endwhile;
              $jobs_search_results_output = ob_get_clean();
              return $jobs_search_results_output;
       endif;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't you want to add 'test' to $jobs_search_results_output as that is what is returned?

Comment: Not at the present time, no.  I was just trying to get the word "test" to appear.  Then I was going to <?php the_title(); ?> and echo the title.